# Node.js parse terminal input

Tags: node.js, ssh

So I have a `ssh2` server, and I want to be able to parse the commands that are entered, I am currently using the `readline` module, but even it outputs special characters when backspace is used, I don't want every keypress, I just want the entire visible line when Enter is pressed, if I type in `testing` and press enter, as expected, my log outputs `Line: "testing" 7 long`, but if I type `testing with backspaces` then press backspace 5 times, and type `oops, mistake`, it outputs `Line: "testing with backspaces⌂⌂⌂⌂⌂oops, mistake" 41 long`.

How do I "parse" these codes to get `Line: "testing with backsoops, mistake" 31 long` out?

```
const rl = readline.createInterface(shell, shell);
rl.on('line', (line) => console.log(`Line: "${line}" ${line.length} long`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, `shell.isTTY` was either `false` or `undefined`, fixed by changing to

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: shell,
  output: shell,
  terminal: true,
});
```